# The global array retains data on refresh in my JavaScript program

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, global-variables, backend

I am trying to make a todo list where I want to add new items to a list using a form. The list works fine, but when I refresh the page, the data already stored in the array is retained. I don't want that.

I want that on every refresh, the older data is lost and fresh items are pushed into the array. But to do this everytime I have to kill and restart the server.

```
initial list:
li1
li2
li3

after item addition:
li1
li2
li3
li4
li5

after refresh: (expected)
li1
li2
li3

after refresh: (actual o/p) 
li1
li2
li3
li4
li5
```

My code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

var Item = ["Home List","Shop List","Bucket List"];

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.set("view engine","ejs");

var options = {
    weekday:"long",
    day:"numeric",
    month:"long"
};

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  var today = new Date();
  var currentDay = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",options);
  res.render("lists",{
      day: currentDay,
      newListItem : Item 
});

});

app.post("/",function(req,res){
    Item.push(req.body.newItem);
    res.redirect("/");
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Have you checked if this is being caused by your browser cache? Also, to calify - when you refresh your browser page, the old array is still there with the additions of you pushing the updated list?

Comment: yes. the old array is still there.

Comment: In idiomatic JavaScript, variable names starting with a capital letter are reserved for constructor functions / classes. Don't use `Items` as the name for a variable that just holds an array, call it `items`.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out. I changed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that would require the ability to distinguish between the browser making a GET request for `/` because the user pressed refresh and the browser making a GET request for `/` for any other reason … and HTTP *really* isn't designed for that.

"Refresh" means "Give me the latest version of this resource". It doesn't imply that the resource should change in response to the request (unless the resource is something like a page designed to show the current time … but the change there is triggered by the change in time and not the refresh itself).

If you want to reset the array, then write an endpoint explicitly designed to reset it, then provide the user with a form and submit button that POSTs to that URL.

```
app.post("/reset",function(req,res){
    Item = ["Home List","Shop List","Bucket List"]
    res.redirect("/");
});
```